# ASP.Net Swashbuckle - store swagger.json in repo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, swagger, swashbuckle

so i use swashbuckle to generate my swagger doc.

When I run the project it generates a swagger.json which in turn is used to generate the doc. The swagger.json is accessible via the url *host/swagger/v1/swagger.json.*

But if I see it right, this swagger.json exists only when I run the program. Is it possible to save it in the directory each time to make it available as a file in repo as well?

Comment: You can save the json file and then reference it in code, but I see no point in going in such direction, as you would have to remove the reference each time you want it auto-generated again